# Syslog driver not working with docker compose and elk stack

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, docker-compose, syslog

I want to send logs from one container running `my_service` to another running the `ELK` stack with the `syslog` driver (so I will need the `logstash-input-syslog` plugin installed).

I am tweaking [this elk image](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker) (and tagging it as `elk-custom`) via the following `Dockerfile-elk`

(using port `514` because [this seems to be the default port](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html))

```
FROM sebp/elk

WORKDIR /opt/logstash/bin

RUN ./logstash-plugin install logstash-input-syslog

EXPOSE 514
```

Running my services via a `docker-compose` as follows more or less:

```
 elk-custom:
    # image: elk-custom
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-elk
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
      - 9200:9200
      - 5044:5044
      - 514:514

  my_service:
    image: some_image_from_my_local_registry
    depends_on:
      - elk-custom
    logging:
     driver: syslog
     options:
       syslog-address: "tcp://elk-custom:514"
```

However:

> ERROR: for b4cd17dc1142_namespace_my_service_1  Cannot start service
>   my_service: failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp: lookup
>   elk-custom on 10.14.1.31:53: server misbehaving
>
> ERROR: for api  Cannot start service my_service: failed to initialize
>   logging driver: dial tcp: lookup elk-custom on 10.14.1.31:53: server
>   misbehaving ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: Apparently nothing seems to be listening on port `514`, cause from within the container, the command `netstat -a` shows nothing on this port....no idea why...

Comment: Try changing `tcp://elk-custom:514` to `tcp://127.0.0.1:514` and see if that helps

Comment: yep. that seems to do the job ... my service stack now seems to start... proceeding with further logstash configuration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `tcp://127.0.0.1:514` instead of `tcp://elk-custom:514`. Reason being this address is being used by `docker` and not by the container. That is why `elk-custom` is not reachable.

So this will only work when you map the port (which you have done) and the elk-service is started first (which you have done) and the IP is reachable from the docker host, for which you would use `tcp://127.0.0.1:514`

Comment: So the actual log forwarding will be done by the docker daemon, and he is **not** aware of the hostnames, whilst each container / service defined within `docker-compose` **is** aware of each other's host name? Is this the case?

Comment: Any suggestion how this works on `rancher`? Neither of `127.0.0.1` or `elk-custom` (i.e. the service name) work, as they cause the same issue: `dial tcp: lookup elk-custom on 10.14.1.31:53: server misbehaving`

Comment: I think you might have to use http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/latest/en/cattle/internal-dns-service/. `<Service>.<stackname>` or something like that. Check the article